# How to handle/convert facebook exponential post id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app which is subscribed for realtime udpates to one of my facebook page. Everything is working fine. Only problem is sometimes I get updates from facebook with exponential post id, for example, 3.79476065496E+14

Now I cannot use that id to get the actual post. Can anyone tell me how to overcome this problem? Is there any way to tell facebook to give a specific format of id or any way to convert that exponential id to normal id?

Comment: You are obviously using a language that tries to interpret post ids as integers. Go figure out how to make it treat them as strings instead.

Comment: @CBroe It is nothing to do with the language. Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Facebook put it intentionally for the posts from users who did not give read stream permission to my app. This is a privacy measure from facebook so that I can not get unauthorized posts through realtime updates using api call.